# Installed numpy and other dependencies but can't seem to get the path set correctly

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, dependencies

I am installing dependencies for python for the first time in VS code. Python was previously installed. I am using Ubuntu on WSL and my file structure is within that folder for Ubuntu. I installed numpy, matplotlib and PyTorch for a guided project I want to do. After installing all packages everything seemed fine however the file from the project to verify the dependencies are correctly setup results in an error that the module (import numpy as np) can not be found. In searching numpy documentation I found that I may need to add a line to my .bashrc file which I did add the following: export PYTHONPATH=/home/stevenseb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages  ....after making this change I get a much more detailed error for which I haven't been able to find helpful documentation. (further below I have posted a list of installed packages)

```
type hestevenseb@DESKTOP-PJJSAIC:~/stock-prediction-model$ /usr/bin/python3.10 /home/stevenseb/stock-prediction-model/project.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stevenseb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/home/stevenseb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/home/stevenseb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stevenseb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/home/stevenseb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "/home/stevenseb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/usr/bin/python3.10"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.26.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stevenseb/stock-prediction-model/project.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/stevenseb/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) from e
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.re
```

pip install gives me this:

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ ----------
aiohttp                  3.9.1
aiosignal                1.3.1
alpha-vantage            2.3.1
async-timeout            4.0.3
attrs                    23.1.0
certifi                  2023.7.22
charset-normalizer       3.3.2
contourpy                1.2.0
cycler                   0.12.1
distlib                  0.3.7
filelock                 3.12.4
fonttools                4.47.0
frozenlist               1.4.1
fsspec                   2023.12.2
idna                     3.6
importlib-resources      6.1.1
Jinja2                   3.1.2
kiwisolver               1.4.5
MarkupSafe               2.1.3
matplotlib               3.8.2
mpmath                   1.3.0
multidict                6.0.4
networkx                 3.2.1
numpy                    1.26.2
nvidia-cublas-cu12       12.1.3.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12   12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12   12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12 12.1.105
nvidia-cudnn-cu12        8.9.2.26
nvidia-cufft-cu12        11.0.2.54
nvidia-curand-cu12       10.3.2.106
nvidia-cusolver-cu12     11.4.5.107
nvidia-cusparse-cu12     12.1.0.106
nvidia-nccl-cu12         2.18.1
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12    12.3.101
nvidia-nvtx-cu12         12.1.105
packaging                23.2
Pillow                   10.1.0
pip                      23.3.2
pipenv                   2023.9.8
platformdirs             3.10.0
pyparsing                3.1.1
python-dateutil          2.8.2
requests                 2.31.0
setuptools               68.2.2
six                      1.16.0
sympy                    1.12
torch                    2.1.2
triton                   2.1.0
typing_extensions        4.9.0
urllib3                  2.1.0
virtualenv               20.24.5
yarl                     1.9.4
zipp                     3.17.0
```

This is the setup file I try to run to verify the dependencies:

```
import numpy as np

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries 

print("All libraries loaded")
```

I have installed python packages using pip successfully however, the environment seems unable to access the packages. I updated PATH in .bashrc but still am experiencing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer myself, I will post here in case anyone should have this problem in the future. It seems that I was installing the dependencies globally instead of creating an environment to install within. Which is explained at this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial  Once I followed the steps to create an environment using .venv I was able to install the dependencies and they passed the verification.